# Lumen 5.2 make:test command is missing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, lumen, laravel-testing

I have installed Lumen 5.2.8. I am trying to unit test the app using phpunit. But when I tried to run the command `php artisan make:test UserTest` it throws an exception

> Command "make:test" is not defined.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm not experienced with Lumen, but my beliefs are that the whole point of Lumen is to have all components disabled to speed performance. Differently from Laravel, you have to install/enable what you'll use so you don't end up with too much unused components. Maybe try researching how to enable this element on Lumen?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `make:test` command, you need to create the TestCase manually.
Follow the documentation [here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing).

Comment: Documentation says there is...why is this functionality missing for so many years when it's explained in documentation. Strange.